# Export Filtered webgrid to Excel - Webmatrix

Tags: excel, razor, webmatrix

I'm trying to export a filtered webgrid to excel, however when the file is downloaded it gave me all the records from the database, then  changed my code to this.

This code is the page where i create the filter:

```
var db = Database.Open("formIGF");
var query = "SELECT * FROM exportTable  WHERE dataEncomenda LIKE @0 ";
var dataPedido = "%" + Request["dataPedido"] + "%";
var data = db.Query(query, dataPedido);
var columns = new[]{"dataEncomenda"};
var grid = new WebGrid(data, columnNames: columns, rowsPerPage:10);


<form method="post">
<div class="grid">

    <div id="grid">
        <label for="dataRecolha">Data do Pedido</label><input id="dataPedido" name="dataPedido" type="text" value="" placeholder="Selecionar um dia"/>
        <input type="submit" />


            @grid.GetHtml(    
                caption: "Numero Total de Entradas: " + @grid.TotalRowCount + " ",
                tableStyle : "table",
                alternatingRowStyle : "alternate",
                headerStyle : "header",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                                        grid.Column("ID"),
                                        grid.Column("dataEncomenda", "Data da Encomenda")
                )
            )

        <a href="GenerateExcel.cshtml?cond=@Request["dataPedido"]" target="_blank">Exportar para Excel</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And this is the code for the page that will export to excel:

```
@{
Layout = null;
var db = Database.Open("formIGF");
var dataPedido = Request.QueryString["dataPedido"];
var data = db.Query(dataPedido);
var columns = data.First().Columns;
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
}


<table style="border: 1px solid #a59f9f;">
<tr style="font-weight: bold">
@foreach(var column in columns){
    <td style="border: 1px solid #a59f9f;">@column</td>
}
</tr>
@foreach(var row in data){
    <tr>
    @foreach(var column in columns){
        <td style="border: 1px solid #a59f9f;">@row[column]</td>
    }
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Then i got an error: 
    Value cannot be null or an empty string. Parameter name: commandText

That means that no value is being passed right ?

On my url i got this:

```
http://localhost:44552/GenerateExcel.cshtml?cond=04-06-2014
```

That value should not pass to my querystring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing a query string value that does not exist. You have named it `cond`, but are using `Request.QueryString["dataPedido"]` to get the value. That should be

```
var dataPedido = Request.QueryString["cond"];
```

Not only that, but you are then passing the value as a SQL command to the `Database.Query` method. It is not a valid sql command. You have missed that bit out in your changes:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM exportTable  WHERE dataEncomenda LIKE @0 ";
var dataPedido = "%" + Request.QueryString["cond"] + "%";
var data = db.Query(query, dataPedido);
```

Comment: Ok, so i've changed that and gave me another error:

Incorrect syntax near '04'. It has something to do with the value that i'm trying to pass. The value is 04-06-2014

Comment: Thanks a lot again Mike. Worked very nice.

Comment: Mike i'm sorry to bother you again, but i'm struggling with something. I was thinking what if the user wants the records from a date range. And i've tried this on my webgrid page.

var dataPedido = "%" + Request["dataPedido"] + "%";
    var dataFim = "%" + Request["dataFim"] + "%";
    var query = "SELECT * FROM exportTable WHERE dataEncomenda BETWEEN '" + dataPedido + "' AND '" + dataFim + "'";

To collect the data, but my webgrid appears empty. Can you give me some lights ? Sorry

Comment: What data type is `dataEncomenda` in the database?

Comment: Not ideal for dates, but you can use `<` and `>` e.g. `"SELECT * From ExportTable WHERE dataEncomenda >= @0 AND dataPedido <= @1"`. Then `var data = db.Query(query, dataPedido, dataFim);`

Comment: But dataPedido is not a column. It's just the name of the input where i put the date

Comment: Change it to dataEncomenda